# if condition satisfied then it need to start loop from beginning means it need to start from 0

Tags: python, list, if-statement

"""{note: if any name match the it need to start loop from beginning means it need to start from 0  to length of list}"""

```
> list[xyz……]
> for x in range(len(list)):
>     if x[1]=="any name":
>         print("1 name match")
>     else:
>         print("not match")
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a hard time understanding what it is you are asking. Please edit your question to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a code where when the if condition returns true then the loop should start from beginning then I would suggest using while loop not if.

### Using for loop

Because the for loop do auto-increment i.e., in for loop if you assign the counter any value explicitly it won't affect the execution and it will auto increment the value assigned to the counter by the loop i.e., the below code will run just 10 times.

```py
for i in range(10):
    if i == 5:
        i = 0
    print(i)
```

It will print 0 instead of 5 when i is 5 but it wont affect the code execution.

### Using while loop

So using the while loop is a better option. As if I run the same code using while loop it will run infinitely.

```py
i = 0
while i < 10:
    if i == 5:
        i = 0
    print(i)
    i += 1
```